# Strange error running PHP tester script for aMember

Tags: php, amember

I'm trying to set up the [aMember Pro](http://www.amember.com/p/) membership software on my Windows 7 machine.  I have properly installed PHP, and I have installed the ionCube loader, required for the trial version of aMember Pro.  When I run the Tester.php script provided by aMember, to check if the web server machine has all the requirements for aMember, I get several repeats of the following error message in my browser, followed by a clearer, Failed (enable_dl disabled in php.ini) error message.  I'm very intrigued by what causes all the repeats of the "Split()" error though.  Any explanations?

```
Warning: split(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Helsinki' for '2.0/no DST' instead in C:\Development\PressMart\aMember\Web\tester.php on line 28 Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in C:\Development\PressMart\aMember\Web\tester.php on line 28 Warning: eregi(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
```

Comment: can you post the code where u uses the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php.ini uncomment or add the line stating:

> date.timezone =

So for Helsinki it would be:

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Helsinki"
```

Make sure you restart your server after saving the php.ini